# How to avoid wobble in beamer overlay inside tcolorbox? (inside tabular)

Tags: beamer, overlays

I have a table with several values witch I need to highlight during a presentation. I used `tcolorbox` to distinguish these data from the rest and `colorbox` to the highlight.

The problem is the text keeps wobbling around. As the first text gets highlighted it moves right and the second line moves down. Also there's an extra line in the `tcolorbox` environment which only disappears at the end.

MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage{fixltx2e} 
\usepackage{soul}               % to striketrhourhg text
\usepackage{tcolorbox}          % fancy colored boxes


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[c,fragile]

    \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=lightgray,
        colframe=white,
        rounded corners=all]
        \begin{tabular}{ l l }
            \only<1>{\(a=7\)  & \(cI=8\) \\}
            \only<2->{\(a=7\) & \colorbox{yellow}{\(cI=8\)} \\}       

            \only<-3>{\(b=2\) & \(dS=3\)\\}
            \only<4>{\(b=2\) & \colorbox{yellow}{\(dS=3\)} \\}
            \only<5->{\colorbox{yellow}{\(b=2\)} & \(dS=3\) \\}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{tcolorbox}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Wobbling text]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, let's say your are asking a question about

- how to make `\alert` works like `\colorbox` instead of `\textcolor`; and
- how to stabilize these `\colorbox`es?

The first question is simple since Beamer provide `\newcommand<>`. 
Now you can define a `\boxalert<2,4>{}` working just like `\alert<2,4>{}`.

```
\newcommand<>\boxalert[1]{
    \alt#2{\colorbox{yellow}{$#1$}}{$#1$}
```

For the second, make sure your contents are put inside a `\colorbox` all  the time:

```
\newcommand<>\boxalert[1]{
    \alt#2{\colorbox{yellow}{$#1$}}{\colorbox{lightgray}{$#1$}}
```

and the following code gives stable result:

[image]

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=lightgray,colframe=white,rounded corners=all]
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            \boxalert<2,4,6,8>{a=7} & \boxalert<3,4,7,8>{cI=8} \\
            \boxalert<5,6,7,8>{b=2} & \boxalert<      0>{dS=3} \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}
```

---

If pseudo-transparent background is not desired, `tcolorbox`, which seems to be used by you already, gives a way to define a real transparent background:

```
\renewcommand<>\boxalert[1]{
    \alt#2{\tcbox[colback=yellow,frame empty]{$#1$}}{\tcbox[colback=red,opacityback=0,frame empty]{$#1$}}
}
```

[image]

Note that the spacing is inconsistent. I guess that is inevitable while having `colorbox`, `beamercolorbox`, and `tcolorbox` in the same document.